# php mutilthreading accessing a array variables

Tags: php, pthreads

How to access a array variables using pthread, i have created a thread class names **"AccessVariable"**, whoose task is to create 4 thread and access the array named **"$arr"**, need some pointer on how to acieve this as i 'm very new in this coding

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
class AccessVariable extends Thread {
    public $arr = array("12","33","21","3211","3214","34","23423");  
    public function __construct($arg) {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }
    public function run() {
        if ($this->arg) {
            $tmp_value = $this->getValue();
            printf('%s: %s %d -finish' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg, $tmp_value);
        }
        $this->synchronized(function($thread) {
                    $thread->getValue();
                }, $this);
    }
    public function getValue() {
        //Get Array Variable
    }
}
// Create a array
$stack = array();
//Iniciate Miltiple Thread
foreach (range("A", "D") as $i) {
    $stack[] = new AccessVariable($i);
}
// Start The Threads
foreach ($stack as $t) {
    $t->start();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations you will find useful:

- Class entry defaults are unsupported - zend has object handlers but no entry handlers,   when an entry is declared object handlers are obviously not suitable for calling as they work with instances. To work around this, set your defaults in constructors.
- Variables intended for sharing among multiple contexts should extend a pthreads definition; pthreads objects functions as objects, and associave arrays and indexed lists, the default PHP implementation of these things is unprepared for multi-threading.
- Synchronizing on an object is only useful if you intend to use synchronization methods while in the synchronized block (closure/function in php); only synchronize if you intend to wait on, or notify others waiting on and object

-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

class SharedArray extends Stackable {
    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->merge($array);
    }

    public function run(){}
}


class AccessSharedArray extends Thread {
    public $shared;
    public $arg;

    public function __construct($shared, $arg) {
        $this->shared = $shared;
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }

    public function run() {
        if ($this->arg) {
            $tmp_value = $this->shared[$this->arg];
            printf('%s: %s %d -finish' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg, $tmp_value);
        }
    }
}

$shared = new SharedArray(
    array("12","33","21","3211","3214","34","23423"));
// Create a array
$stack = array();

foreach (range(0, 3) as $i) {
    $stack[] = new AccessSharedArray($shared, $i);
}

// Start The Threads
foreach ($stack as $t) {
    $t->start();
}

foreach ($stack as $t)
    $t->join();
?>
```

There are many examples on github and included in the distribution to help you to get to know pthreads well enough to use it. Multi-threading is not like using a new database, or http client. It is complex and powerful, I implore you to read carefully and fully every example included even if you think it is irrelevant to the task at hand; the knowledge will serve you well whatever.

In addition to examples, there is much info in past bug reports on github, so if you have a problem and there doesn't seem to be a solution in an example then search the issues list on github before reporting any bugs.