# how to update the php class array values while using pthreads

Tags: php, class

```
class Field extends Thread{
        public $dataFields;

        public function addValue($table,$key,$data){
          print_r($this->dataFields[$table]);
          echo "\ndata: ".$data."\n";
          if(isset($this->dataFields[$table][$key])){
              $this->dataFields[$table][$key]= $data;
              echo "yes\n";
            }
          else echo "no\n";
          print_r($this->dataFields[$table]);

         }

         public function setVariables($con){
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from property,city limit 1");
            $row=mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $propData[$value->table][$value->name]="";
            }
            $propData["property"]["portalId"]=2;
            $propData["property"]["area"]="delhi";
            $this->dataFields=$propData;
            $this->addValue("property","id","1");
            //print_r($this->dataFields);
            $this->dataFields["property"]["id"]=1;
            var_dump($propData);
            var_dump($this->dataFields);
        }
    }
```

as you can see the code I am updating the value of array through function addValue, if the key is set in the dataFields array then it will get updated but in this its not happening when I try to call the function:

addValue("property","id","1"); through function setVariables() 
(see the output below)

it prints the value of $data it prints "yes".
The class variable dataFields is not getting updated.

[Edit]
When I am using Threads extended class it don't get updated but when I don't use Thread extended class then it get updated.

```
    Array                                 
    (                                             
        [id] =>                                   
        [portalId] => 2                          
        [area] => delhi                           
    )                                             

    data: 1                                 
    yes                                           
    Array                                         
    (                                             
        [id] =>                                   
        [portalId] => 2                          
        [area] => delhi
    ) 
    array(2) {                        
         ["city"]=>                              
         array(3) {                              
           ["id"]=>                              
           string(0) ""                          
           ["name"]=>                            
           string(0) ""                          
           ["otherNames"]=>                      
           string(0) ""                          
         }                                                                
         ["property"]=>                          
         array(3) {                             
           ["id"]=>                              
           string(0) ""                          
           ["portalId"]=>                        
           int(2)                                
           ["area"]=>                            
           string(5) "delhi"                     
         }
        }
    array(2) {
          ["city"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["name"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["otherNames"]=>
            string(0) ""
          }
          ["property"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["portalId"]=>
            int(2)
            ["area"]=>
            string(5) "delhi"
           }
        }
```

Comment: Please show us your input, exact output and your expected output. (Works fine for me) Also show us your **full** code

Comment: Why is the output: `data: DEFAULT` and not `data: 1` ? Please show us the full code

Comment: sorry I copied output of different test case I have corrected it now!

Comment: Change `addValue("property","id","1");` -> `$this->addValue("property","id","1");` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Change your `print_r()` calls to `var_dump()` and look into the source code if there are any "hidden" characters

Comment: there is alot of code so i just posted the required part of code and thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: var dupm produced this output
array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["portalId"]=>
          int(2)
          ["area"]=>
          string(5) "delhi"
        }

        data: 1
        yes
        array(3) {
          ["id"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["portalId"]=>
          int(2)
          ["area"]=>
          string(5) "delhi"
        }

Comment: If it is a lot of code please post a pastbin link here otherwise please show us your full code! Also try it with another array or id like `area` does this works?

Comment: I have updated it .. please check it! The rest of the code is not in not required here.

Comment: It has to work i see no error! (What is the output of `var_dump($propData);` ?)

Comment: when I tried to update it like this $this->dataFields["property"]["id"]=1; It still didnt get updated.

Comment: 1. Restart the server and run the script again/new 2. Please post a pastbin of the entire code! (Also see this: http://ideone.com/BseNTT It just works totally fine (Just replaced the db stuff with: `$propData["property"]["id"] = "";`))

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the following works for me in 5.6.3:

```
class Field {
    public $dataFields;

    public function addValue($table,$key,$data){
      print_r($this->dataFields[$table]);
      echo "\ndata: ".$data."\n";
      if(isset($this->dataFields[$table][$key])){
          $this->dataFields[$table][$key]= $data;
          echo "yes\n";
        }
      else echo "no\n";
      print_r($this->dataFields[$table]);

     }

     public function setVariables(){
        $propData["property"]["id"] = '';
        $propData["property"]["portalId"]=2;
        $propData["property"]["area"]="delhi";
        $this->dataFields=$propData;
        $this->addValue("property","id","1");
        //print_r($this->dataFields);
    }
}

$field = new Field;
$field->setVariables();
```

with output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [portalId] => 2
    [area] => delhi
)

data: 1
yes
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [portalId] => 2
    [area] => delhi
)
```

I would recommend reinstalling the latest version of PHP.

Comment: This doesn't help OP or anyone, it's not a answer. You can put a comment under OP's question. Everyone could say: It works for me and we would have 200 answers here!

Comment: @ayushlodhi The output which you posted on your question is this copied from the source code of your script?

Comment: @ayushlodhi Did you clicked: `right click on your page -> view source code` and copied the var_dump from there?

Comment: I copied form the terminal

Comment: @Rizier123 You pretty much posted the exact same thing as me in the 13th comment of the question lol

Comment: @Mex Don't see any comment from you under OP's question

Comment: @ayushlodhi Copy the output from the source code and NOT the terminal: `right click on your page -> view source code` and show us this output, this could be the solution (That you copy the output from the source code and not from the page or terminal is VERY important)

Comment: @Rizier123 I am running the code in terminal, I am not using apache

Comment: @Rizier123 You posted a link to code that is almost identical to mine is what I mean. Kinda spooky!

Comment: @ayushlodhi If you have a apache server or can easily install it do it and show us the output from the source code! (Also please post a pastbin for the full code that we have that and can take a look)

Comment: @Mex Ah, yeah, but your code is better formatted :D

Comment: @Rizier123  found the culprit, actually I have inherited the thread class using extends, I mean class Field extend Thread{} and when I use thread extended class the variable is not getting update but when i don't use thread extend class then the variable is getting updated

Comment: @ayushlodhi We would have seen that if you did what i already said with the first comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376508/how-to-update-the-php-class-array-values/28377013?noredirect=1#comment45093161_28376508 post the full code :D

Comment: @Rizier123 I have learned my lesson, from the next time I will, sorry for troubling you, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @ayushlodhi np, if you want you can answer your own question and mark it as accept or if you want you can delete it

Comment: but I still don't understand why is that so? I mean how thread is effecting this?

Comment: @ayushlodhi You would have to show us the code of this class :D

Comment: I am using pthread library here, I read somewhere that normal implementation of associative array don't work with multithreading.

Comment: here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136489/php-mutilthreading-accessing-a-array-variables)
but I still don't know how to update associative array